# Cannot Start Scrapyd

Tags: python, scrapy

When I want to start scrapyd inside a scrapy project. I get the error:

`server: error: Scrapyd is not available in this system`

I install scrapy through the source package, the command `scrapy version -v` displays the following messages:

```
Scrapy  : 0.15.1
lxml    : 2.3.4.0
libxml2 : 2.7.8
Twisted : 12.0.0
Python  : 2.7.3 (default, Jun  3 2012, 12:07:40) - [GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)]
Platform: Linux-2.6.18-92.el5-x86_64-with-redhat-5.2-Tikanga
```

I have checked the installed packages, the scrapyd folder exists in parallel with scrapy folder. All files like script.py exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Scrapy daemon (`scrapyd`) is a separate package for Ubuntu and probably for RedHat as well, if you can find it.  So you need to install both packages:

```
$ aptitude install scrapy-0.14
$ aptitude install scrapyd-0.14
```

And in RedHat it would be similar, something like:

```
$ rpm -i scrapy-0.14.rpm
$ rpm -i scrapyd-0.14.rpm
```